# How to write an XPath query for text within <script> using PhantomJS

Tags: json, xpath, web-scraping, phantomjs, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape some specific content that sits within the `<script>` section of a page (at the bottom of the page before the end of the  tag. It is my understanding that this can't be done with regular XPath, so I will be using PhantomJs cloud via SEOTools for Excel plugin.

Please see code below:

```
<script> window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = {"questions":{"list":{},"status":{}},"sites":{"list":{"SEOTest":{"joined":"2016-04-17T22:00:31.000Z","threshold":[],"abn":"8724483318952",
```

I want to be able to scrape the text after "ABN" field, so the xpath would return "8724483318952". Does anybody know how this can be done with xpath?

Comment: In your sample there _is no text after the "abn" entry_. Your question seems to be missing something.

Comment: Hi, thanks for having a look. I've clarified my post but basically I want to be able to scrape the text after "ABN" field, so the xpath would return "8724483318952"

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the desired target string value of `"8724483318952"` you can use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
substring-before(substring-after(script,'abn&quot;:'),',')
```

It gets the desired string from the `<script>` tag and its output is

> "8724483318952"

---

The signature of `XPathUrl` is, according to [this link](https://seotoolsforexcel.com/xpathonurl/):

```
=XPathOnUrl(
   string url, 
   string xpath, 
   string attribute, 
   string xmlHttpSettings, 
   string mode
) : vector
```

So the whole expression could look like this:

```
 =XPathOnUrl(A2,"substring-before(substring-after(//ul[@class='headshot']/script,'abn&quot;:'),',')")
```

I'm not sure that this expression really does work, but it should give you a pretty precise idea of how to handle XPath expression generally.

Comment: Perhaps i'm out of my element. I get an error when i use that type of xpath within SEOTools for excel. Typically my xpaths look like: 

=XPathOnUrl(A2,"(**//ul[@class='headshot'])[1]")**

Comment: @TobyJamesOlsen: I updated my answer with a different suggestion.